# Can I boot a Ubuntu live install ISO from a usb key on my Powerbook G4?

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb

So, I have a Powerbook G4 17" right now and the ribbon cable connecting the ODD drive to the motherboard is dead. Somebody has torn the cable from the board and the cable is completely knackered. The connector on the board looks fine, as is the connector on the ODD drive, but I have no way of getting a new ribbon cable at this time.

So, is there any way of installing Ubuntu onto the powerbook via a mounted ISO on a USB drive? The Powerbook is already running Ubuntu, but the previous owner had pulled the power half way through an update, so, it's pretty much ruined. I have several versions of Ubuntu for PPC already on my hard drive, but would there be a way of booting a mounted ISO file from a USB drive through OpenFirmware or something? If not, I guess I'll buy a broken powerbook for a small amount of money and get the ribbon cable out of it, but if there is a way, i'd greatly appreciate it if somebody could point me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the answer is yes yes because you can just run Ubuntu live off your flash drive. Even if the hard drive is disconnected from the system, the hard drive is not involved in the process of running Ubuntu live unless you want to install Ubuntu to your hard drive.
First, boot from your flash drive and choose "Try Ubuntu without installing" and press the Enter or Return key.
[image: First screen you see after booting from flash drive]

Then, Ubuntu loads the kernel, does a bunch of other stuff, and then you should see the Unity desktop if everything went well. If it doesn't work that well, post what happened.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this isn't what I asked at all. I asked if there was any way to boot a Ubuntu live ISO via a USB drive on a PowerPC system. There is no ODD (Optical Disk Drive) available, and as it is an Apple device, it is not very open. I know Ubuntu runs on this particular device because it is already running it, only the previous owner managed to corrupt the install. And since I don't have a CD/DVD drive onboard right now, I need to be able to reinstall Ubuntu from a USB.